# Your server doesn’t meet the following requirements to run Craft

Tags: php, requirements, mcrypt

Here's the error I get: "You have an insecure version of crypt installed. Please update PHP to 5.3.7 or later". I have PHP Version 5.3.2 installed on my Ubuntu server and cannot switch to a new version no matter what I do. I also tried to php5enmod mcrypt and it gives me command not found. I did the classic

sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install php5;
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt;

Can you guys help? My phpinfo() doesnt show mcrypt as being installed even though it is installed actually. I am out of ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would install PHP via a third-party repository. I use Ondřej Surý's and I'm pretty happy with it. It installs PHP 5.5.

https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5

Comment: I did that and I'm still at PHP 5.3. Here's the exact terminal commands I executed:

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable;
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install php5

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting 5.3 because the php5-oldstable is 5.4. Why not use the latest php5 repository? Also, what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I have a Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS server and I did try using the latest php5 repository

Comment: That is your problem right there. Ubuntu 10.04 is not supported in either of those repositories. The more recent one supports 12.04 and up and the oldstable only supports 12.04. Ubuntu is seeing that and falling back on it's own php5 package which is probably 5.3.2. You need to update Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you on a VPS? The best option is make a new instance / linode / droplet, etc.  Upgrading a production server is risky at best. But if you're feeling adventurous, updating to 12.04 is pretty straightforward iirc. That'll let you run Craft without a ppa—at least until 3 comes out. But if it were me, I'd get on 14.04 asap. You'll have to jump to 12.04 first. The biggest change is Apache 2.4 which changes some of the config syntax so if you have a lot of websites/services on that server or  a mission critical website, that can be problematic. Of course backup first!

Comment: Thank you guys for the support... Yes. I will think about moving to at least 14.04 asap but I will need to devote some time for that. Untill then, i can work without Craft since Craft was just a nice to have and not a critical component.